# Bind param not working

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to update informations in my database
this is the html page:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Modifier informations:</legend>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label class="form-control">Nom</label>
  
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label class="form-control">Adresse</label>
  
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="adresse">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label class="form-control">Date fe FONDATION</label>
  
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date_creation">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label class="form-control">Détails</label>
  
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="details"></textarea>
</div>
 </div> 
  <br>
  <button style="float: right" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
  
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

this is update.php

```
<?php
    require "DB/config.php";
    include "Service/Association.php";
    /*require '../connected.php';*/
    session_start();

    $ASS = new Association("1",$_POST["title"],$_POST["adresse"],$_POST["details"],$_POST["date_creation"]);

     $c=new config();
     $conn = $c->getConnexion();

    $ASS->ModifierAssociation($ASS,$conn);
```

and this is the method in my association class:

```
function ModifierAssociation($Animaux,$conn){
    try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("update  `association`( `nom`, `adresse`, `details`, `date_creation` )VALUES(:nom,:adresse,:details,:date_creation)");
         

        $nom=$Animaux->getnom();
        $stmt->bindParam(':nom',$nom);

        $adresse=$Animaux->getadresse();
        $stmt->bindParam(':adresse',$adresse);

        $details=$Animaux->getdetails();
        $stmt->bindParam(':details',$details);
        
        $date_creation=$Animaux->getdate_creation();
        $stmt->bindParam(':date_creation',$date_creation);

        print_r($stmt);

        $stmt->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

i get this error

> PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => update `association`( `nom`, `adresse`, `details`, `date_creation` )VALUES(:nom,:adresse,:details,:date_creation) )
>
> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( `nom`, `adresse`, `details`, `date_creation` )VALUES('1','','','')' at line 1

Comment: You're mixing update SQL with insert SQL.

Comment: how can i use the update sql ?

Comment: Just type "mysql update" into Google and you'll have all the answers in the world, no need for Stack Overflow for that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for MySQL `UPDATE` is:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

So you need:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    "UPDATE  `association` SET  
        `nom` =:nom, 
        `adresse` = :adresse, 
        `details` = :details, 
        `date_creation` = :date_creation");
```

Note this will update the entire association table so you should identify the rows you want to update with the `WHERE` clause.